# How do I encapsulate version management for gradle plugins?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl

## Problem

I have a setup of various distinct repos/projects (i.e. `app1`, `app2`, `app3`) that all depend on shared functionality in my `base` package.

The projects also use various other third-party dependencies (i.e. `app1` and `app3` use spring, all of them use `kotlinx-serialization`).
I want to synchronise the versions of all third-party dependencies, so that any project using my base package uses the same version of every third-party dependency. However, I don't want to introduce new dependencies to projects that do not use them (i.e. `app2` does not use spring)

## Solution attempts

For **libraries**, I have been able to solve this with the help of a gradle `platform`, which does exactly what I want - I specify the versions in my base package, then add the `platform` as a dependency to my projects and can then simply add dependencies by name (i.e. `implementation("org.springframework.boot:some-package")`) without having to specify a version number, because it uses the provided value from my `platform`.

However, for **plugins**, I have not been able to do this. Many libraries come with plugins and naturally the plugin should be at the same version as the library. I have tried various approaches, including writing a standalone plugin, but none have worked.

### **Current best idea**

I added `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2")` to the dependencies of my standalone plugin. Then, I added the following code to my standalone plugin:

```kotlin
class BasePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.plugins.apply("org.springframework.boot")
    }
}
```

This works and applies the plugin to my main project at the correct version. However, there are 2 major problems with this:

a) Now **every** project applies the spring plugin, including `app2` (which does not use spring).

b) I have many plugins to manage and no idea how to get the long implementation-string for most of them. I found the `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2"` by looking up the plugin-id on https://plugins.gradle.org/ and then looking at the *legacy plugin application* section, which sounds like I am on the wrong track.

**I just want to manage the versions of plugins and libraries of multiple projects/repos in a central place** - this feels like a fairly basic use case - why is this so hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great and detailed answers about dependency management, but unfortunately none worked to perform cross-project version management for plugins.
It seems that there is no gradle functionality to do this, but I got it working with a bit of a workaround. Here is my (working) approach, in hope that it helps someone else with this:

1. Create a Standalone gradle Plugin
2. In the `build.gradle.kts` of the plugin, include the maven coordinates (not its ID) of every other plugin whose version you want to manage in any of your projects in the dependency block with the `api` keyword. i.e. `api("org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.2")`
3. In the main projects, remove every other plugin from the `plugins` block, so that your custom standalone plugin is the only one remaining.
4. Create a file (i.e. a `plugins.json` or whatever you want) in the project root directory of all main projects and in there supply the plugin IDs of the plugins that you actually intend to use in that project. Just the IDs, no version numbers, i.e. "org.springframework.boot" for Spring's plugin. (Keep in mind that for plugins declared as `kotlin("abc")` you will have to add the prefix "org.jetbrains.com.", as the `kotlin` method is just syntactic sugar for that)
5. In your plugin source code, in the overriden `apply` method, look for. a file named `plugins.json` (or whatever you chose) in the `project.buildFile.parent` directory (which will be the directory of the project using this plugin, NOT of the plugin itself). From this file, read the plugin IDs
6. for every pluginID in the file, call `project.plugins.apply(id)`

How/Why it works:

- The main project `build.gradle.kts` is executed, looks at the plugin block and applies your standalone plugin (which is the only one), which calls its `apply` method.
- This plugin then applies other plugins based on their ID from the file.
- Normally, this will throw an error because these plugins are not found, but because we defined them as dependencies with the `api` keyword in our standalone plugin, they are now available on the classpath and in exactly the version of that import statement.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

> a) Now every project applies the spring plugin, including `app2` (which does not use spring).

It is indeed better to avoid applying too many plugins - and that's why Gradle encourages [reacting to plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#reacting_to_plugins).

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

class BasePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        // don't apply
        //target.plugins.apply("org.springframework.boot")

        // instead, react!
        target.plugins.withType<SpringBootPlugin>().configureEach {
            // this configuration will only trigger if the project applies both
            // BasePlugin *and* the Spring Boot pluging
        }

        // you can also react based on the plugin ID
        target.pluginManager.withPlugin("org.springframework.boot") {

        }
    }
}
```

Using the class is convenient if you want to access the plugin, or the plugin's extension, in a typesafe manner.

You can find the Plugin's class by

- looking in the source code for the class that [implements `Plugin<Project>`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0440e23233edb8c44cfc26429509aa0fa419fade/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin.java#L45),
- in the plugin's build config for the [`implementationClass`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0440e23233edb8c44cfc26429509aa0fa419fade/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/build.gradle#L49),
- or in the published plugin JAR - in the `META-INF/gradle-plugins` directory there will be a file that has the `implementationClass`.

This doesn't help your version alignment problem - but I thought it was worth mentioning!

> b) I have many plugins to manage and no idea how to get the long implementation-string for most of them. I found the `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2"` by looking up the plugin-id on https://plugins.gradle.org/ and then looking at the *legacy plugin application* section, which sounds like I am on the wrong track.

You're on the right track with the "long implementation string" as you call it. I'll refer to those as the 'Maven coordinates' of the plugin.

#### Gradle Plugin Maven Coordinates

The *plugin id* of the Kotlin JVM plugin is `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, but the *Maven coordinates* are `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0` .

[image: screenshot of Gradle Plugin portal for Kotlin JVM plugin, showing how to apply the plugin using the plugins {} block, vs the 'legacy' `apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")]

The 'legacy' part refers to how the plugins are applied, using the `apply(plugin = "...")` syntax. The new way uses the `plugin {}` block, but under the hood, both methods still use the Maven coordinates of the plugin.

If you add those Maven coordinates (with versions) to your [Java Platform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html), then you can import the platform into your project. But where?

#### Defining plugin versions

There are a [lot of ways](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl) to define plugins, so I'll only describe one, and coincidentally it will be compatible with defining the version using a Java Platform.

If you're familiar with buildSrc convention plugins, you'll know that they *can* apply plugins, but they *can't* define versions.

```kotlin
// ./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/kotlin-jvm-convention.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0" // error: pre-compiled script plugins can't set plugin versions!
}
```

Instead, plugin versions must be defined in the build config for buildSrc

```kotlin
// ./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
  // the Maven coordinates of the Kotlin JVM plugin - including the version
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
}
```

This looks a lot more traditional, and so I hope the next step is clean: use your Java Platform!

#### Applying a Java Platform to buildSrc

```kotlin
// ./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
  // import your Java Platform
  implementation(platform("my.group:my-platform:1.2.3"))

  // no version necessary - it will be supplied by my.group:my-platform
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
}
```

Note that this same method will also apply if your projects an 'included build' instead of buildSrc.

Once the plugin versions are defined in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, you can use them throughout your project (whether in convention plugins, *or* in subprojects), they will be aligned.

```kotlin
// ./subproject-alpha/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") // no version here - it's defined in buildSrc/build.gradle.kts
}
```

Comment: `project.plugins.withType()` does not compile, I need a specific class to put in there. What is that class? Do I need to find the java class def of every plugin that I want to manage and put it in there?

Comment: @KotlinLukas Sorry, I missed some of the configuration. I've updated a more complete example. You don't have to use the Class name, you can also use the plugin ID - but then you will lose some type safety if you want to configure the plugin.

Comment: Okay thanks! But how do I configure the version numbers of the plugins in this? There is no option to add a version number in the configuration block from what I can see.
I want: `id("myplugin") version "1.0"` and then in the next lines `id("springplugin")` <- no version and then have my platform configure the plugin version, similar to how platforms work for libraries.

Comment: @KotlinLukas The plugin versions must be set in the `build.gradle.kts` of the project that contains your convention plugin, for example, `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

Comment: But this is what I want to avoid. I DON'T want my main projects (`app1`, `app2` etc), which use my plugin, to have to manage plugin versions.
I want my plugin to specify default version numbers for all other plugins and then the main projects simply have to say which of these plugins should be included (i.e. Spring), but not which version. So that all main projects using v1.0 of my plugin would have the same plugin versions across the entire system and can then all update together when I publish v1.1 of my plugin

Comment: The `build.gradle.kts` of the convention plugins project is that single place.

Comment: I have attempted this, however when importing the conventing plugins artefact into my main projects, the defined plugin versions are not carried over. If I attempt to define a plugin without explicit version number in my main projects, the build does not compile. Syntax such as `id("something") version "123" apply(false)` only works from within the same project, not when importing a distinct artefact

Answer (score 0):

I use version numbers in a `gradle.properties` file for this purpose. Since the introduction of Gradle version catalogs, my approach is probably a bit out of date, but I'll share it here anyway. It's based on the fact that plugin versions can be managed in `settings.gradle.kts` by reading values from the properties file.

In `gradle.properties`:

```
springBootVersion=3.0.2
```

In `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    val springBootVersion: String by settings

    plugins {
        id("org.springframework.boot") version springBootVersion
    }
}
```

And finally in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
}

dependencies {
    val springBootVersion: String by project
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion"))
}
```

Notice that the plugin version is omitted in the build script because it is already specified in the settings file.
And note also that the method for accessing the property in the settings script is slightly different from that in the build script.

Comment: Hey this is a good answer, but to a different question. You describe how to include version numbers *within* a multi-module project, I want to centralise dependencies across multiple projects and repositories (i.e. by using a 'base' project that manages the dependencies, like a platform)

Comment: Oh, I see! I didn't realise exactly what you were trying to do from your initial question. Your comment here actually helped a lot to clarify it for me. Maybe I should leave this here so other answerers know what _not_ to write 